# Can't create a form to upade part of a model field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

This is really frustrating,

I can't and can't find how to create a form (I'm guessing a forms.Form form) to update just one field of a more complex model.

The model has 5 fields, and a form to create, update all of them.

But in a different case i need to let the user update only the title (a field in the model), so i need tried so many things until now (including creating an HTML form by hand and from the view to save it, creating a forms.Form and many more, nothing seem to work), There is no code here because i don't even know which one to put....

Maybe some one can help me with that, I'm sure it is a simple thing, But for some reason i am stuck on this for a long time...

Thank you,
Erez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `ModelForm`s, you just have to define a `fields` attribute in `Meta` as a tuple containing just the names of the fields you want. See the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-a-subset-of-fields-on-the-form).

Comment: Thanks, but from what i know (maybe i am wrong an will be very happy if so) i can not create to form to same model with modelForms, because of the name of the form. I have already one form for all the model using modelForm, called PhotoForm, now i need another form just for the title (i don't want to let the user in this case update all the model, just this field, so how can i create this kind of form if i already have another form using modeForm?

Comment: The name of a model form doesn't matter -- it's just the `model` attribute in `Meta` which determines which model to use.

Comment: I knew i am stupid, Thank you so much.... How much time i spent on this :-)  Thank you so much :-)

Comment: The Only part that is not good about this is that when i use this, it saves the images again and again on the server, I've overridden the save function for the photo model to create and save few images from the original one and the files are being save again and again when ever i am updating...